# RESTful - Possibly unhandled rejection

Tags: java, angularjs

I have a problem that I cannot solve here because, I've created a `backend` system using the `Java API for RESTful Web Services`. I have seen some problems similar to mine here in this forum but I cannot resolve the issue.

```
Possibly unhandled rejection:
{
    "data": {

        "timestamp": 1518840352603,
        "status": 500,
        "error": "Internal Server Error",
        "exception": "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException",
        "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",
        "path": "/postNewProducts"

    },
    "status": 500,
    "config": {

        "method": "POST",
        "transformRequest": [null],
        "transformResponse": [null],
        "jsonpCallbackParam": "callback",
        "url": "http://localhost:9000/postNewProducts",
        "data": {

            "name": "er",
            "price": "34"

        },
        "headers": {

            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Authorization": "Basic MTIzOjEyMw==",
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"

        }

    },
    "statusText": ""

}
```

In the `backend`, It cannot save the data because they are being sent as `null`. So I cannot solve this problem. I'm using `Angular 1.6`

Comment: Please make the log a bit more readable friendly next time.

Comment: Also are you using `Java API for RESTful Web Services`?

Comment: Also @zgue, AngularJS is only for JavaScript, it says in the description when you highlight the tag. `Do not use this tag when you're using Angular 2 or later versions, use the [angular] tag`.

Answer (score 0):

backend

```
@Autowired
private Products_Repo prodrepo;



@GetMapping(value="/getAllProducts")
public Iterable<Products> ListaProduct() {
    Iterable<Products> ListaProduct = prodrepo.findAll();
    return ListaProduct; 

}




@PostMapping("/postNewProducts")
public @ResponseBody Products CadastrarProduct(Products products) {
    return prodrepo.save(products);

}
```

frontend

```
angular.module('app').controller(
```

'ProdutosControllerCreate', function ($scope, ProductsFactory, $http) {

```
$scope.saveproduct = function(){
  var response = $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost:9000/postNewProducts", 
    data: $scope.product
  }).then(function(data, status, headers, config){
    $scope.product = null;
  });
}
```

});

```
<div ng-controller="ProdutosControllerCreate">


<form name="addprodutosform" ng-submit="saveproduct()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Nome do Produto</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="product.name"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Preco</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="product.price"/></td>
        </tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"/></td>
    </table>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Data Integrity Exception happens from backend side:

1) Either some data type you are sending from UI has not same data type defined in Pojo. 
2) Or, The data type you are defining in Pojo is not matching with the data type in Entity 
3) or last one, The Java Entity class has different data type but you are creating column in DB with different data type.

These are most common things for data integrity issue.

Comment: It seems to me an error in the angular because the output of the data is going out null

Answer (score 0):

Okay, but in my backend I have name and price, respectively, in the database, as I used hibernate, it generates name and price, name = varchar (255) and price = int (11) I do not know how to solve it ... in the database I put it to accept null data Null data is being sent to the bank.